# Can we get RSS feeds for the newest, featured, hot, highest-voted, and active questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed

None of these Questions tabs has an RSS feed link at the bottom of the page.  Would it be unreasonable to create feeds for each of the "views" or tabs on the site?

If that's unreasonable, then do you have statistics showing what tabs are most often viewed by users?  Those most popular views would be the ones you would want to at least supply RSS feeds on.

Comment: They do if you're in a particular tag.

Answer (score 1):

All of this already exists.

Please see the html meta tags for each of those pages, or scroll down to the bottom and look for the little orange RSS icon.

edit: oh, you mean /questions. Well, same advice applies:

- newest (duplicates feed on homepage tab)
- hot (duplicates feed on homepage tab)
- votes (would be the same 30 highest voted questions, forever)
- active (duplicates feed on homepage tab)

Basically the feeds you want are on the home page, and the one that isn't doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Could you make these feeds realtime? This way there is no need to poll and we can easily get IM notifications for hit/new/voted/active questions :)