# Is there an RSS feed for "Recently Active Questions"?

Tags: feature-request, feed

I'm looking for an RSS feed that does what a site homepage's "Active" tab (e.g.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) does: shows "Questions that have been asked, answered, or updated recently" in reverse chronological order by the most recent update to those questions.

The RSS link on that tab is just the generic [Recent questions feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds) which only shows *new* questions, not ones with recent answers or updates.

I've seen [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151519) which mentions additional questions feeds:
  .../feeds/featured
  .../feeds/hot
  .../feeds/week   and
  .../feeds/month
None of these do what I am looking for.
I've tried   .../feeds/active   and   .../feeds/recent   but those do not exist.

[Can we get RSS feeds for the newest, featured, hot, highest-voted, and active questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29783) is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and the answer suggests the feed for Active is there on the homepage, but it's not.

**Is there an RSS feed for Recently Active Questions?**
**If not, can we get one?**