# Home page RSS feed links are incorrect

Tags: bug, feed

The various tabs on the per-site Top Questions homepage have, at the bottom of the right nav, an RSS link for the selected tab.  However, these are currently not correct for the active tab, for most of the tabs.

For tab...   the RSS link is ...
[Bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bugs)      [Monthly questions feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/month)
[Reqs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=requests)       not present (but that's probably correct)
[Active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=active)       [Recent questions feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds) (probably by design, but [not actually "active" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333287))
[Bountied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties)     
[Bountied questions feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured)  (correct)
[Hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot)        
[Bountied questions feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured)
[Week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=week)      
[Hot questions feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/hot)
[Month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=month)      
[Weekly questions feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/week)

Other sites don't have all those tabs, but the ones which are present are incorrect in the same way.